# i have this problem related login page with redirect Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function redirect() in

Tags: php

I want to create a login page but I'm stuck on an error. I had more errors but I went through and fixed them all except for this one which still has me lost all day so if anyone can help me I'd appreciate it, thanks.

```
<?php require_once("includes/header.php"); ?>

<?php
if(!$session->signin())
{
    redirect('login.php');
}
?>
```

these files are all working classes page

```
<?php

require_once ("config.php");
require_once ("database.php");
require_once ("user.php");
require_once ("functions.php");
require_once ("senssion.php");
?>
```

I expect to see my login page but it returns

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error:  Call to undefined function redirect() in

Comment: perhaps you've missed the file that have the `redirect()` function in it?

Comment: you use codeigniter???

Comment: hasta dhana thanks i got it

Comment: <opinion>Instead of redirecting to ```login.php```, you should ```require("login.php");``` and have ```login.php``` call ```exit``` at it's end. This way, if your user get's logged out, he will not end up loosing his url but still see the login form. Even though he will get directed somewhere else upon login, he THEN can just press back to get where he actually wanted to be once logged in. Also remember crash recovery with multiple tabs - no one wants to end up on ```/login.php``` on 5 tabs ...</opinion>

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to redirect in php, the best way is using the `header()` function.

Syntax is:

```
header("Location: /examplelink");
```

It will then go to the page that you are wanting after your link, if you want the home directory you do not put anything after the slash. E.g:

```
header("Location: /");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: remember to ```exit(0)``` after ```header```, or script execution will continue.